# How to change the value of the input field of custom WordPress admin page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a custom `WordPress Admin page` with `input fields`. I would like to change the `values` of them in the `constructor` based on the `database`. I have no idea how to access them...

The function which is called in the constructor and which will handle the `database init`. The database `column names` and `input field ids` are the same:

```
public function update_inputs(){
    global $wpdb;
    $columns = $wpdb->get_col("DESC `dbtable-admin`", 0);
    foreach($columns as $column){
        /*if($column == field name){
            field name.value = $wpdb -> get_var("SELECT $column FROM `dbtable-admin`");
        }*/
    }
}
```

`Field setup`:

```
public function setup_fields()
{
    $fields = array(
        array(
            'uid' => 'page_name',
            'label' => 'Oldal neve',
            'section' => 'custom_page_settings',
            'type' => 'text',
        ) ,
        //Others are the same.
     );
     foreach ($fields as $field)
    {

        add_settings_field($field['uid'], $field['label'], array(
            $this,
            'field_callback'
        ) , 'custom-main-menu', $field['section'], $field);
        register_setting('custom-main-menu', $field['uid']);
    }
}
```

So I need to somehow access the fields outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registered settings are stored in wordpress wp_options table by uid, you can access them using the [get_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) function. As your column name is same as your uid u can get the value of the field by get_option($column). You can update the values using [update_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)($column, $new_value).